# PHP - Connect to sftp from private key through socks5 proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy, phpseclib, fsockopen

I'm trying to connect to sftp with rsa private key auth, through proxy.

```
use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$proxyHost = 'proxy-host';
$proxyPort = 1080;
$fsock = fsockopen($proxyHost, $proxyPort);

$host = 'sftp.hostname.com';
$login = 'sftp_login';
$privatekey = file_get_contents('sftp_private.ppk');
$password = new RSA();
$password->loadKey($privatekey);
$request = "CONNECT $host:22 HTTP/1.0\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";

if(fputs($fsock, $request) != strlen($request)) {
  exit("premature termination");
}
while ($line = fgets($fsock, 1024)) {
    if ($line == "\r\n") {
      break;
    }
    //echo $line;
}
$sftp = new SFTP($fsock);
if (!$sftp->login($login, $password)) {
  exit('Login Failed');
}
```

I get  the "Login Failed" exit.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you also posted this on https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1460. Nothing wrong with that but I'm just posting the link so that people responding here can consult that link for reference.

Comment: yes, it is. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting 
https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1460 :

> Port 1080 is typically used for SOCKS5 proxies - not HTTP proxies.
>
> Assuming you're using a SOCKS5 proxy then something like this should
>   work:
>
> ```
> // SSH connection info
> $port = 22;
> $address = 'localhost';
>
> // SOCKS5 connection info
> $fsock = fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 1080, $errno, $errstr, 1);
> if (!$fsock) {
>     throw new \Exception($errstr);
> }
>
> $port = pack('n', $port);
> $address = chr(strlen($address)) . $address;
>
> $request = "\5\1\0";
> if (fwrite($fsock, $request) != strlen($request)) {
>     throw new \Exception('Premature termination');
> }
>
> $response = fread($fsock, 2);
> if ($response != "\5\0") {
>     throw new \Exception('Unsupported protocol or unsupported method');
> }
>
> $request = "\5\1\0\3$address$port";
> if (fwrite($fsock, $request) != strlen($request)) {
>     throw new \Exception('Premature termination');
> }
>
> $response = fread($fsock, strlen($address) + 6);
> if (substr($response, 0, 2) != "\5\0") {
> echo bin2hex($response) . "\n";
>     throw new \Exception("Unsupported protocol or connection refused");
> }
>
> $ssh = new SSH2($fsock);
> $ssh->login('username', 'password');
> echo $ssh->exec('ls -latr');
> ```
>
> That said, SOCKS5 has a lot more bells and whistles then this sample
>   code currently accommodates. Really, what'd be good is a full on
>   SOCKS5 class.

Hope it will help someone else.